# How to handle index files in a distributed Lucene cluster?

Tags: indexing, lucene, cluster-computing

We are using Lucene in our application, and the index files saved in the disk of  the same server where the application run.

The index files are  almost 2Gb at the moment, and they maybe updated sometime, for example, when new data are inserted into the database, we may have to rebuild that part of index and add them.

So far so good since there is only one application server, now we have to add another to make a cluster, so I wonder how to handle the index files?

BTW, out application should be platform independent, since our clients use different os like Linux, and some of them even use the cloud platform with different storage like Amazon EFS or Azure storage.

Seems I have two opinions:

1 Every server hold a copy of the index files, and the make them synchronized with each other.

But the synchronized mechanism will depend on the OS, we tried to avoid this. And I am not sure if it will cause conflict if two server update the index files with different documents at the sometime.

2 Make the index file shared.
Like 1), the file share mechanism is platform aware. Maybe save them to the database is an alternative, but how about the performance? I have thought to use memcached to save them, but I have not find any examples.

How do you handle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you should look into [Compass project](http://www.compass-project.org/overview.html). Compass allowed to store Lucene index in database and distributed in memory data grids like GigaSpaces, Coherence and Terracotta. Unfortunately this project is outdated and last version was released at 2009.  But you can try adapt it for your propose.

Another option, to look at [HdfsDirectory](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/branch_5x/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/store/hdfs/HdfsDirectory.java) that support a storing a index in HDFS file systems. I see only 5 classes in package [`org.apache.solr.store.hdfs`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/branch_5x/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/store/hdfs) , so it will be relatively easy to adapt them to storing index into in-memory caches like memcached or redis.

Aslo I find a project on github for [RedisDirectory](https://github.com/maxpert/RedisDirectory), but it initial stage and last commit was at 2012. I can recommend it only for reference.

Hope this help you find a right solution.